# I've installed vestacp but I can't access the control panel

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx

I started a fresh instance of ubuntu on aws.

I ran the vesta installation:

```
curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh

bash vst-install.sh
```

I had removed the admin group before installing so I didn't have to --force the installation.

During the vesta setup I entered my email address and hostname `seoplay.co.uk`

I get my login credentials and everything seemed to have setup correctly, but when I go to my `www.seoplay.co.uk:8083` or `https://seoplay.co.uk:8083/` I get a webpage not available.

Not sure what other information to show you guys but here's a htop screenshot...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't entered 8083 as a custom tcp rule in my aws secruity group.

Comment: What to do if i hasn't removed the admin group and did  --force installation?